# Drawing of domain of $~D= \left\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \Bigg| 1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 2^2,~~0\leq y\leq x \right\} ~$

Tags: geometry, multiple-integral

$$
D= \left\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \Bigg| 1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 2^2,~~0\leq y\leq x \right\} 
$$

$$
I:=\iint_{D} x\log \left(x^2+y^2 \right) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y
$$

I want to know the exact domain of $~D~$

I think that at least the green-painted domain is a subdomain of $~D~$

I've come up with the dought that black domain may also be a subdomain of $~D~$

Can it be?

[image]

Moreover, I've been studying math completely with self-taught one so I can't have a confidence that whether I can replace $~\log~$ to $~\ln~$
without point(s) subtracted of an exam.

Comment: $D$ is the union of your two (green and black) subdomains. [You can replace $\log$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) with $\ln$ here, and everywhere unless another base is specified like in $\log_{10}$ or $\log_2$ ($\ln$ is $\log_e$).

Comment: Regarding log vs. ln, you'll need to ask the teacher setting the exam. There are no universal laws for such things.

Comment: @HansLundmark I'll do so.

Answer (score 1):

Owing to @Anna Bauval, I think I got the solution of the double integral.

Since it is too natural for me using $~\ln~$ than $~\log~$,I use natural logarithm here for now without asking the person who made this math problem.

$$
D= \left\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \Bigg| 1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 2^2,~~0\leq y\leq x \right\} 
$$

$$
I=\iint_{D} x\log \left(x^2+y^2 \right) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y
$$

$$
E:= \left\{ (r,\theta)~~ \Bigg| 1\leq r\leq 2,~~ 0\leq\theta\leq {\pi \over 4 } \right\} 
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
  x=r\cos(\theta)\\
  y=r\sin(\theta)     
\end{cases}
$$

$$\begin{align}
I&=\iint_{E} r^2\cos(\theta)\ln \left(r^2 \right) \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\cdots\\
&= \left(\int_{1}^{2}r^2 \ln \left(r^2 \right) \mathrm{d}r\right) \left(\int_{0}^{{\pi \over 4 } } \cos(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta  \right)\\
&=\cdots\\
&= \sqrt{2} \left\{ {4 \over 3 }\ln(4)- {7 \over 9 } \right\}  
\end{align}$$